# Symlink is not working in my local machine

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, symlink

I'm using Xampp setup in Windows 7 machine. I am trying to configure sub-folder module in Drupal 7. But it says "Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)" error which stops me in configuring the module properly. And subfolder module functionality is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Windows error message indicating that the current user does not have permission to create symbolic links.  By default, this privilege is granted to administrators only.  Your options for fixing this are either to run as administrator (which of course is risky for normal day-to-day use) or explicitly enable the privilege for the user running this process.

This question's accepted answer describes the step-by-step details for enabling the privilege for a specific user:

https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user