# Yii2 symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)

Tags: yii2

I tried to run my Yii2 application on Localhost, XAMPP for PHP 5.6.32 and Windows 8 but I got this error:
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

How do I resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112037

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- The problem mostly occurs when you don't start the server/Xampp on local with administrative privilege. Try to start Xampp from the control panel if you are on windows.
- Alternatively, you can use the option to disable the symlink by adding the `assetManager` setting under the `components` section in your config file (for yii-advance app it can be the `common/config/main.php` or the `config/web.php` in the yii-basic app)

  ```
  'components'=>[
       'assetManager' => [
           'linkAssets' => false
       ],
  ]
  ```

**UPDATE**

There could be a possibility that you get the above error while running any of the commands on the terminal like while contributing into the yii2 repo you have to run the command `php build/build dev/app basic <fork>` during which it creates a symlink and throws the above error, and after trying both of the above you still dont get it to work in that case **you might have to use the default command prompt for the windows by starting it as an administrator** and then run the above command.

Comment: the downvoter didn't left any comments so i could improve, maybe there wasn't any reason and he was here just for revenge,:( poor soul, I pray for you to get better soon

Comment: "Xampp on local with administrative privilege". Thanks.

Comment: In which file I have to add this?

Comment: @KetanBorada you need to add this inside the config/main.php

Answer (score 1):

In case you are **in development mode I recommend you to leave the 'linkAssets' parameter set to 'true'** so you don't have to delete the assets every time you make a change. (In production it is recommended to set it to 'false').

**To solve your problem run xampp as administrator**:

To run the control panel as administrator, you can right click on the shortcut icon (Start > XAMPP > XAMPP Control Panel) and choose the option "More > Run as administrator".  I leave you a link where it is better explained: [Execute xampp as admin](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/otros/xampp-instalacion-windows.html#:%7E:text=Para%20ejecutar%20el%20panel%20de,M%C3%A1s%20%3E%20Ejecutar%20como%20administrador%22.)